# Why can't I install EinsteinPy on Anaconda in Mint?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, package, linux-mint

I run Linux Mint 20.2 and have EinsteinPy installed in the local directory which I used to use when running programs from the Terminal.

Recently, when I tried to use the anaconda IDE to do programming and tried installing the package from the base terminal of Conda, I failed!

I used,

```
(base) manu@KillingMachine:~$ conda install einsteinpy
```

and the results are as follows:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - einsteinpy

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


(base) manu@KillingMachine:~$ $ conda install -c conda-forge einsteinpy
$: command not found
(base) manu@KillingMachine:~$  conda install -c conda-forge einsteinpy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 767, in read_chunked
        chunk = self._handle_chunk(amt)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 711, in _handle_chunk
        value = self._fp._safe_read(amt)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 625, in _safe_read
        chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
        for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
        for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 793, in read_chunked
        self._original_response.close()
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
        raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 261, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
        subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
        self.load()
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 210, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 375, in _load
        raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 701, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
        r.content
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 836, in content
        self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
      File "/home/manu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 761, in generate
        raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

`$ /home/manu/anaconda3/bin/conda install -c conda-forge einsteinpy`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/manu/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/manu/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/manu/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/manu/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/manu/anaconda3/bin:/home/manu/anaconda3/bin:/home/manu/anaconda3
                          /condabin:/home/manu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sb
                          in:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
            XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
         XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/manu/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/manu/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/manu/.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.21.5
         python version : 3.9.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/manu/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/manu/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/manu/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/manu/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/manu/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/manu/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Linux/5.4.0-74-generic linuxmint/20.2 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]: y
Upload successful.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

    $ conda config --set report_errors true
```

Please help me know, where I went wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: The error you get is a connection reset from requests. It most likely means your anaconda environment is not updated. Try `conda update --all`, if that doesnt work I recommend move off conda and start using pyenv instead, it lets you micromanage all packages and python binaries, it also installs all the c-libs needed to compile most of the stuff that do not have wheels.

Comment: But I installed the latest version of it already and besides I work in Windows as well, there it was no problem at all, can there be any other reason to it?

Comment: On linux you need to have wheels for lots of platforms and glibc versions, if you do not have wheels(binary build for your platform), you can compile it but that requires lots of lib*-dev and correct glibc. Try a standalone venv and install einsteinpy there and see if it compiles. if it works then compare the `pip freeze` and you will probably see that the condaversion is too old for min20.2.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the inputs.